# For loop with a timeout doesn't seem to work and gives weird numbers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I want to make a countdown in javascript, with simple variables, for loop, set timeout.

I get stuck when trying to make a for loop update realtime (every second) right now I get -1 in webpage.

```
//HTML PART

<p id=timer>0</p> 


//JS PART
var timer = 10; 
var text = "";

function f() {
    for (timer; timer > 0; timer--) {
    text += timer + "<br>";
    }
    timer--;
    if( timer > 0 ){
        setTimeout( f, 1000 );
    }
}
f();

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timer;
```

Please explain the error and if I'm doing any stupid mistakes

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `for` loop? It brings `timer` to `0`, and then `timer--;` brings it to `-1`.

Comment: ok and then theres just a for loop without any timings.

Comment: @4castle I'm making a timer...

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What do you want the values of `text` and `timer` to be after the loop is finished?

Comment: timer will be 0 and text is just a way to show things in html

Comment: Ok, so if `timer` is supposed to be `0`, what's unexpected about what the program currently outputs? What did you want it to output?

Comment: It should spawn a countdown one by one, from 10 to 0 every 1 second. Right now I get static value of "-1" on the screen that doesn't do anything.

Comment: do you want to count up or count down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to show timer value from 10 to 0 by changing the value every second. If so, you can do like this:
1. You need to correct your html by putting quotes around timer like this `<p id="timer">0</p>`
2. You need to remove for loop as I have commented.
3. Move `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timer;` inside function f().

```js
var timer = 10;
//var text = "";

function f() {
  //for (timer; timer > 0; timer--) {
  //    text += timer + "<br>";
  //}
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timer;
  timer--;
  if (timer >=0) {
    setTimeout(f, 1000);
  }
}
f();
```

```html
<p id="timer">0</p>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! But I wanna ask dumb question, if you use setTimeout function INSIDE a function f why do you need to specify it again inside itself (before 1000 miliseconds)?

Comment: @PetrasVilkelis For that you need to understand what setTimeout does? It basically says that call function mentioned in the first parameter after every miliseconds mentioned in the second parameter. By mentioning the same function f, you are kind of looping over and calling f() again and again. What you were trying to do in the for loop.

Comment: It is better to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when the aim is to display text, not HTML.

Comment: @trincot How do we guard against hidden elements via css if we use textContent?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so, I provided comments in code for explanation:

```
var count = 10;
function timer(targetValue) {
    // display first number on screen
    document.getElementById("timer").textContent = count;

    // decrease count by 1
    count--;

    // check if timer is still grater than target value
    if (count >= targetValue) {
        // call timer() function every second to update
        setTimeout(timer, 1000, targetValue);
    }
}
timer(0);
```

Counts down from 10 to 0.

Want to count down from 10 to 5? Simply use `timer(5)`